# QQml_colorProvider: no color provider has been set?

Tags: qt, qml

I try to learn QML and follow official demo to run it, and write a simple qml file and then run qmlscene command to run it, but it show warring and then failed.

The **hello.qml** file:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 100
    color: "red"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello, World!"
    }
}
```

And then run it it command line:

```
E:\QT-learn>qmlscene hello.qml
Warning: QQml_colorProvider: no color provider has been set!
file:///E:/QT-learn/hello.qml:6 Invalid property assignment: color expected
```

My Environment:
Win10 system
Python3.8 64bit
PyQt5.15

Comment: What version of Qt and OS do you use? With Qt 5.15 on Linux it works correctly

Comment: @eyllanesc I had updated my post with my system environment.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, how did you install PyQt5? Have you used pip or other method?

Comment: I use pip to install PyQt5 and related packages.

Comment: try installing a previous version, for example 5.14

Comment: If i comment color line, it run fine.

Comment: @eyllanesc It also show same error with PyQt5.14.0

Comment: How did you install qmlscene? since qmlscene doesn't come with PyQt5

Comment: I think i use pip install PyQt5-tools, so i use qmlscene to run it.

Comment: mmm, that package probably has the bug, why don't you install Qt?

Comment: I had install pure Qt C++ version, but i am not familiar with it(C++) and don't know how to use it.

Comment: No, I am not saying use C++ but rather that Qt provides the official tools like qmlscene.

Comment: I had found a  `pyqt5qmlscene.exe` program in my python scripts directory , and it run well.